# How to create Directories Structure

Tags: c#

I am having a problem in creating multiple directories structures,

I know how to create a directory iam using these line of code to create a directory because there are more than 50 directories and 70 subdirectories in my project .
I want to create directories structure at one one click

```
    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        string Path = "C:\\Test\\Test1";
        Directory.CreateDirectory(Path);
    }
```

But I want to creating directories structure like this

EXAMPLE :-

```
      1)string Path1 = "C:\\Test";

      2)string Path2 = "C:\\TestABC";

      3)string Path3 = "C:\\Test1\\123";

      4)string Path3 = "C:\\Test2\\145";
```

By this example i want to create this all strucure at a time.

There would be a great apreciation if someone could help me,

Thanks In Advance.

Comment: @G Basha
: what is your question?

Comment: i want to create multiple directories because there are many directories in different path

Comment: You know how to do it, now do it in a loop.

Answer (score 7):

lets assume that you have an array of strings containing all your directories you want to create.

```
string[] path = {...}; //all the directories
for(int i = 0; i < path.Length; i++)
{
    Directory.CreateDirectory(path[i]);
}
```

put this code in your function.

**Edit**: as you requested.
your code would be something like this:

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    string[] path = {"C:\\Test", "C:\\TestABC", "C:\\Test1\\123", "C:\\Test2\\145"}; //all the directories
    for(int i = 0; i < path.Length; i++)
    {
        Directory.CreateDirectory(path[i]);
    }
}
```

Comment: what is this line string[] path = {...};  i am getting an error that identifier expected

Comment: you should fill the variable `path` (which is an array) with all the directories you want to create. I put "..." there because I don't know what they are. Where do you store the directories you want to create?

Comment: can u  please give a example sir, I  am in c#.There would be a great apreciation if u could help me, my prob will solve

Comment: there are in my example u can see it

Answer (score 2):

Just to expand on Yasser's post in case your not sure how to fill in the path[] array.

```
vate void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    string[] path = { 
                        "C:\\Test", 
                        "C:\\TestABC", 
                        "C:\\Test1\\123", 
                        "C:\\Test2\\145",
                        "C:\\AddMoreDirectoriesHere"
                    };
    for (int i = 0; i < path.Length; i++)
    {
        Directory.CreateDirectory(path[i]);
    }
}
```

Hope this helps

Answer (score 2):

Just expending Yasser's post its better to check if directory exists before creating a directory

```
 private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        //all the directories
        string[] path = {"C:\\Test", "C:\\TestABC", "C:\\Test1\\123", "C:\\Test2\\145"}; 
        for(int i = 0; i < path.Length; i++)
        {
           if(!Directory.Exists(path[i])
                 Directory.CreateDirectory(path[i]);
        }
    }
```

Comment: why check? if the dir specified already exists, it will be ignored, won't be?